# Códigos CSS en beautifulsoup con python

Tags: html, python, css, beautifulsoup

Estoy realizando scrapping a la página de es.stackoverflow.com con BeautifulSoup para registrar el título y los votos que tiene cada pregunta en la página principal.

Ya he obtenido los titulares, pero se me complica la estructura de los votos que es la siguiente:

```
  <div class="votes">
            <div class="mini-counts">
                    <span title="0 votos">0</span></div>
            <div>votos</div>
        </div>
```

Leyendo otras publicaciones llegué a que podría acceder a través de los códigos CSS, que si no me equivoco en este caso sería:

```
"div.votes > div.mini-counts > span"
```

AL ejecutar el código, me aparece como respuesta una lista en blanco "[]"
Luego, mi código es el siguiente:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page= requests.get("https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&pagesize=50")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

tabla= soup.find(class_="snippet-hidden")  #El soup find me permite encontrar un elemento
titulares = soup.find_all(class_="question-summary") #El soup me permite encontrar distintos elementos (2 o mas)
select_votos = soup.select("div.votes > div.mini-counts > span")

#pregunta= [item.find(class_="question-hyperlink").get_text() for item in titulares]
votos= [item.get("title") for item in select_votos]


print(votos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está correcto, lo que debe suceder es que  todas las preguntas están con 0 votos. En este caso no se generan los div anidados. Cuando no hay votación en en la pregunta solo se genera

```
      <div class="votes"/>
```

Edición:

en las paginas es.stactkoverflow/questions las clases son:

```
      selector="div.votes > span.vote-count-post > strong"
      votos=[s.text for s in html.select(selector)]
      print(votos)
```

resultado:

['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '3', '1', '0', '-5', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '1', '2', '0', '1', '0', '3', '1', '4', '0', '1', '-2', '4', '3', '1', '3', '1', '0', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '3', '0', '0']

El la pagina de inicio es.stackoverflow .com si contiene las clases que indicas.

Comment: El problema es que las preguntas si tienen votos y, aunque estuvieran sin votos, lo que espero es que me aparezca en el print "0 votos" y no vacío como me aparece ahora

Comment: en las paginas /questions las clases cambian

Comment: Ahora me ha funcionado perfecto tanto para los votos como para los comentarios, según el hipervinculo los codigos css cambian, por eso no me funcionaba. Gracias!